# How to convert complex JSON object to pandas dataframe for machine learning

Tags: python, pandas

I have some json like this:

```
{"0": {"name": "Vanilla Cream Ale", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/1633/vanilla-cream-ale", "method": "All Grain", "style": "Cream Ale", "batch": 21.8, "og": 1.055, "fg": 1.013, "abv": 5.48, "ibu": 19.44, "color": 4.83, "ph mash": -1, "fermentables": [[2.381, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 44.7], [0.907, "American - White Wheat", 40.0, 2.8, 17.0], [0.907, "American - Pale 6-Row", 35.0, 1.8, 17.0], [0.227, "Flaked Corn", 40.0, 0.5, 4.3], [0.227, "American - Caramel / Crystal 20L", 35.0, 20.0, 4.3], [0.227, "American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)", 33.0, 1.8, 4.3], [0.113, "Flaked Barley", 32.0, 2.2, 2.1], [0.34, "Honey", 42.0, 2.0, 6.4]], "hops": [[14.0, "Cascade", "Pellet", 6.2, "Boil", "60 min", 11.42, 33.3], [14.0, "Cascade", "Pellet", 6.2, "Boil", "20 min", 6.92, 33.3], [14.0, "saaz", "Pellet", 3.0, "Boil", "5 min", 1.1, 33.3]], "hops Summary": [[28.0, "Cascade (Pellet)", 18.34, 66.6], [14.0, "saaz (Pellet)", 1.1, 33.3]], "other": [["2 oz", "pure vanilla extract", "Flavor", "Boil", "0 min."], ["1 oz", "pure vanilla extract", "Flavor", "Bottling", "0 min."], ["1 tsp", "yeast nutrient", "Other", "Boil", "15 min."], ["1 each", "whirlfloc", "Fining", "Boil", "15 min."], ["4 each", "Vanilla beans - in 2oz Vodka", "Other", "Secondary", "0 min."]], "yeast": ["Wyeast - K\u00f6lsch 2565", "76%", "Low", "56", "70", "Yes"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 16, "views": 289454},
"2": {"name": "Sierra Nevada Pale Ale Clone", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/28546/sierra-nevada-pale-ale-clone", "method": "All Grain", "style": "American Pale Ale", "batch": 24.6, "og": 1.055, "fg": 1.013, "abv": 5.58, "ibu": 39.79, "color": 8.0, "ph mash": 5.67, "fermentables": [[5.216, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 92.7], [0.412, "American - Caramel / Crystal 60L", 34.0, 60.0, 7.3]], "hops": [[14.0, "Magnum", "Pellet", 15.0, "Boil", "60 min", 22.62, 8.3], [14.0, "Perle", "Pellet", 8.2, "Boil", "30 min", 9.51, 8.3], [28.0, "Cascade", "Pellet", 7.0, "Boil", "10 min", 7.66, 16.7], [56.0, "Cascade", "Pellet", 7.0, "Boil", "0 min", 0, 33.3], [56.0, "Cascade", "Pellet", 7.0, "Dry Hop", "4 days", 0, 33.3]], "hops Summary": [[14.0, "Magnum (Pellet)", 22.62, 8.3], [14.0, "Perle (Pellet)", 9.51, 8.3], [140.0, "Cascade (Pellet)", 7.66, 83.3]], "other": [["1 each", "Crush whilrfoc Tablet", "Water Agt", "Boil", "10 min."]], "yeast": ["Fermentis - Safale - American Ale Yeast US-05", "76%", "Medium", "54", "77", "Yes"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 26, "views": 271945},
"3": {"name": "Zombie Dust Clone - ALL GRAIN", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/5916/zombie-dust-clone-all-grain", "method": "All Grain", "style": "American IPA", "batch": 22.7, "og": 1.061, "fg": 1.016, "abv": 5.94, "ibu": 62.42, "color": 8.5, "ph mash": 5.81, "fermentables": [[5.33, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 81.7], [0.513, "American - Munich - Light 10L", 33.0, 10.0, 7.9], [0.227, "German - CaraFoam", 37.0, 1.8, 3.5], [0.227, "American - Caramel / Crystal 60L", 34.0, 60.0, 3.5], [0.227, "German - Melanoidin", 37.0, 25.0, 3.5]], "hops": [[21.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "First Wort", "0 min", 15.57, 8.6], [35.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "15 min", 21.11, 14.3], [35.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "10 min", 15.43, 14.3], [35.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "5 min", 8.48, 14.3], [35.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "1 min", 1.83, 14.3], [84.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Dry Hop", "7 days", 0, 34.3]], "hops Summary": [[245.0, "Citra (Pellet)", 62.42, 100.1]], "other": [], "yeast": ["Fermentis - Safale - English Ale Yeast S-04", "75%", "High", "54", "77", "Yes"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 10, "views": 208996},
"4": {"name": "Russian River Pliny the Elder (original)", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/37534/russian-river-pliny-the-elder-original-", "method": "All Grain", "style": "Imperial IPA", "batch": 22.7, "og": 1.072, "fg": 1.018, "abv": 7.09, "ibu": 232.89, "color": 6.33, "ph mash": -1, "fermentables": [[6.01, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 87.2], [0.272, "American - Caramel / Crystal 40L", 34.0, 40.0, 3.9], [0.272, "American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)", 33.0, 1.8, 3.9], [0.34, "Corn Sugar - Dextrose ", 46.0, 0.5, 4.9]], "hops": [[98.0, "Columbus", "Pellet", 15.0, "Boil", "90 min", 171.54, 28.0], [21.0, "Columbus", "Pellet", 15.0, "Boil", "45 min", 31.54, 6.0], [28.0, "Simcoe", "Pellet", 12.7, "Boil", "30 min", 29.81, 8.0], [28.0, "Centennial", "Pellet", 10.0, "Aroma", "0 min", 0, 8.0], [70.0, "Simcoe", "Pellet", 12.7, "Aroma", "0 min", 0, 20.0], [28.0, "Columbus", "Pellet", 15.0, "Dry Hop", "13 days", 0, 8.0], [28.0, "Centennial", "Pellet", 10.0, "Dry Hop", "13 days", 0, 8.0], [28.0, "Simcoe", "Pellet", 12.7, "Dry Hop", "13 days", 0, 8.0], [7.0, "Columbus", "Pellet", 15.0, "Dry Hop", "5 days", 0, 2.0], [7.0, "Centennial", "Pellet", 10.0, "Dry Hop", "5 days", 0, 2.0], [7.0, "Simcoe", "Pellet", 12.7, "Dry Hop", "5 days", 0, 2.0]], "hops Summary": [[154.0, "Columbus (Pellet)", 203.08, 44.0], [133.0, "Simcoe (Pellet)", 29.81, 38.0], [63.0, "Centennial (Pellet)", 0.0, 18.0]], "other": [], "yeast": ["Wyeast - American Ale 1056", "75%", "Med-Low", "60", "72", "No"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 6, "views": 193832},
"5": {"name": "Spotted Clown (New Glarus Spotted Cow clone)", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/672/spotted-clown-new-glarus-spotted-cow-clone-", "method": "All Grain", "style": "Cream Ale", "batch": 20.8, "og": 1.054, "fg": 1.014, "abv": 5.36, "ibu": 21.27, "color": 5.94, "ph mash": -1, "fermentables": [[2.722, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 50.0], [0.907, "American - Munich - Light 10L", 33.0, 10.0, 16.7], [0.567, "Flaked Corn", 40.0, 0.5, 10.4], [0.794, "Flaked Barley", 32.0, 2.2, 14.6], [0.227, "American - Caramel / Crystal 10L", 35.0, 10.0, 4.2], [0.227, "American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)", 33.0, 1.8, 4.2]], "hops": [[14.0, "Cascade", "Pellet", 6.7, "Boil", "60 min", 12.67, 33.3], [14.0, "german select", "Pellet", 5.8, "Boil", "20 min", 6.64, 33.3], [14.0, "Willamette", "Pellet", 5.2, "Boil", "5 min", 1.96, 33.3]], "hops Summary": [[14.0, "Cascade (Pellet)", 12.67, 33.3], [14.0, "german select (Pellet)", 6.64, 33.3], [14.0, "Willamette (Pellet)", 1.96, 33.3]], "other": [["1 each", "whirlfloc", "Fining", "Boil", "15 min."], ["1 tsp", "yeast nutrient", "Other", "Boil", "15 min."]], "yeast": ["Wyeast - K\u00f6lsch 2565", "75%", "Low", "56", "70", "Yes"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 5, "views": 190059},
"6": {"name": "Chocolate Vanilla Porter", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/29265/chocolate-vanilla-porter", "method": "All Grain", "style": "Robust Porter", "batch": 22.7, "og": 1.06, "fg": 1.016, "abv": 5.77, "ibu": 31.36, "color": 34.76, "ph mash": -1, "fermentables": [[2.268, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 35.6], [1.361, "United Kingdom - Brown", 32.0, 65.0, 21.4], [0.907, "American - Munich - Light 10L", 33.0, 10.0, 14.2], [0.454, "American - Chocolate", 29.0, 350.0, 7.1], [0.454, "American - Caramel / Crystal 10L", 35.0, 10.0, 7.1], [0.454, "Flaked Oats", 33.0, 2.2, 7.1], [0.227, "American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)", 33.0, 1.8, 3.6], [0.113, "Brown Sugar", 45.0, 15.0, 1.8], [0.136, "Corn Sugar - Dextrose", 46.0, 0.5, 2.1]], "hops": [[28.0, "East Kent Goldings", "Pellet", 5.4, "Boil", "60 min", 18.38, 40.0], [21.0, "East Kent Goldings", "Pellet", 5.4, "Boil", "30 min", 10.59, 30.0], [21.0, "Willamette", "Pellet", 4.7, "Boil", "5 min", 2.39, 30.0]], "hops Summary": [[49.0, "East Kent Goldings (Pellet)", 28.97, 70.0], [21.0, "Willamette (Pellet)", 2.39, 30.0]], "other": [["6 oz", "organic cocoa powder", "Flavor", "Boil", "15 min."], ["1 oz", "pure vanilla extract", "Flavor", "Boil", "0 min."], ["1 tsp", "yeast nutrient", "Other", "Boil", "15 min."], ["2 each", "Vanilla bean", "Flavor", "Secondary", "--"]], "yeast": ["Wyeast - Irish Ale 1084", "73%", "Medium", "62", "72", "Yes"], "rating": 4, "num rating": 1, "views": 188822},
"7": {"name": "Zombie Dust Clone - EXTRACT", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/5920/zombie-dust-clone-extract", "method": "Extract", "style": "American IPA", "batch": 18.9, "og": 1.063, "fg": 1.016, "abv": 6.16, "ibu": 70.18, "color": 8.98, "ph mash": 5.41, "fermentables": [[2.722, "Dry Malt Extract - Extra Light", 42.0, 2.5, 70.6]], "hops": [[28.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "First Wort", "0 min", 25.02, 12.5], [28.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "15 min", 20.35, 12.5], [28.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "10 min", 14.87, 12.5], [28.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "5 min", 8.18, 12.5], [28.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "1 min", 1.77, 12.5], [84.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Dry Hop", "7 days", 0, 37.5]], "hops Summary": [[224.0, "Citra (Pellet)", 70.19, 100.0]], "other": [], "yeast": ["Fermentis - Safale - English Ale Yeast S-04", "75%", "High", "54", "77", "Yes"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 9, "views": 184124},
"8": {"name": "Southern Tier Pumking clone", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/16367/southern-tier-pumking-clone", "method": "All Grain", "style": "Holiday/Winter Special Spiced Beer", "batch": 20.8, "og": 1.083, "fg": 1.021, "abv": 8.16, "ibu": 50.22, "color": 15.64, "ph mash": -1, "fermentables": [[6.804, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 75.9], [0.907, "American - Victory", 34.0, 28.0, 10.1], [0.34, "American - Caramel / Crystal 80L", 33.0, 80.0, 3.8], [0.907, "pumpkin", 1.75, 13.0, 10.1]], "hops": [[28.0, "Magnum", "Pellet", 15.0, "Boil", "50 min", 41.13, 50.0], [28.0, "Sterling", "Pellet", 8.7, "Boil", "10 min", 9.1, 50.0]], "hops Summary": [[28.0, "Magnum (Pellet)", 41.13, 50.0], [28.0, "Sterling (Pellet)", 9.1, 50.0]], "other": [["0.75 lb", "Demerara sugar", "Flavor", "Boil", "1 hr."], ["0.25 lb", "Light Brown sugar", "Flavor", "Boil", "1 hr."], ["0.75 tsp", "Fresh ground ginger", "Spice", "Boil", "5 min."], ["3 each", "Ceylon cinnamon sticks", "Spice", "Boil", "5 min."], ["0.50 tsp", "Whole cloves", "Spice", "Boil", "5 min."], ["0.50 tsp", "Nutmeg", "Spice", "Boil", "5 min."], ["0.50 tsp", "Allspice", "Spice", "Boil", "5 min."], ["1 each", "Vanilla Bean vodka solution (see notes for exact quantities)", "Spice", "Secondary", "--"], ["1 tsp", "Pumpkin pie spice", "Spice", "Secondary", "--"], ["1 tsp", "Capella water soluble Graham Cracker Extract (purchased online)", "Spice", "Secondary", "--"]], "yeast": ["Wyeast - American Ale 1056", "75%", "Med-Low", "60", "72", "No"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 15, "views": 181369},
"9": {"name": "Bakke Brygg Belgisk Blond 50 L", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/89534/bakke-brygg-belgisk-blond-50-l", "method": "All Grain", "style": "Belgian Blond Ale", "batch": 50.0, "og": 1.062, "fg": 1.012, "abv": 6.52, "ibu": 18.54, "color": 4.35, "ph mash": -1, "fermentables": [[11.0, "Castle Malting Pilsen 2RP/2RS", 37.0, 1.8, 88.0], [0.5, "Castle Malting Abbey", 33.0, 17.4, 4.0], [1.0, "Farin, hvit", 46.0, 0.0, 8.0]], "hops": [[64.0, "Hallertau Mittelfruh", "Pellet", 4.0, "Boil", "60 min", 13.36, 56.1], [50.0, "Hallertau Mittelfruh", "Pellet", 4.0, "Boil", "15 min", 5.18, 43.9]], "hops Summary": [[114.0, "Hallertau Mittelfruh (Pellet)", 18.54, 100.0]], "other": [], "yeast": ["Fermentis - Safbrew - Specialty Ale Yeast T-58", "80%", "High", "12", "25", "No"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 5, "views": 172811},
"10": {"name": "Mango Habanero IPA", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/61082/mango-habanero-ipa", "method": "All Grain", "style": "Imperial IPA", "batch": 20.8, "og": 1.086, "fg": 1.018, "abv": 8.88, "ibu": 98.09, "color": 8.55, "ph mash": 5.69, "fermentables": [[6.804, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 81.1], [0.907, "American - Caramel / Crystal 20L", 35.0, 20.0, 10.8], [0.454, "Flaked Wheat", 34.0, 2.0, 5.4], [0.227, "Rolled Oats", 33.0, 2.2, 2.7]], "hops": [[35.0, "Magnum", "Pellet", 15.0, "Boil", "60 min", 57.62, 16.7], [28.0, "Centennial", "Pellet", 10.0, "Boil", "30 min", 23.62, 13.3], [35.0, "Centennial", "Pellet", 10.0, "Boil", "10 min", 13.93, 16.7], [28.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.1, "Boil", "1 min", 1.47, 13.3], [28.0, "Zythos", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "1 min", 1.46, 13.3], [14.0, "Centennial", "Pellet", 10.0, "Dry Hop", "0 days", 0, 6.7], [28.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 10.0, "Dry Hop", "0 days", 0, 13.3], [14.0, "Zythos", "Pellet", 11.0, "Dry Hop", "0 days", 0, 6.7]], "hops Summary": [[35.0, "Magnum (Pellet)", 57.62, 16.7], [77.0, "Centennial (Pellet)", 37.55, 36.7], [28.0, "Citra (Pellet)", 1.47, 13.3], [42.0, "Zythos (Pellet)", 1.46, 20.0], [28.0, "Citra (Pellet)", 0, 13.3]], "other": [["1 each", "Whirlfloc Tab", "Fining", "Boil", "5 min."], ["44 oz", "Pureed Frozen Mango", "Flavor", "Boil", "5 min."], ["1 each", "Pureed Habanero Pepper", "Flavor", "Boil", "5 min."], ["32 oz", "Organic Mango Juice", "Flavor", "Secondary", "0 min."], ["1 each", "Sliced Habanero Pepper", "Flavor", "Secondary", "0 min."]], "yeast": ["White Labs - California Ale Yeast WLP001", "76.5%", "Medium", "68", "73", "Yes"], "rating": 5, "num rating": 6, "views": 172664}
```

}

This json represents Beer Recipes, and some of the fiels are nested objects, for example fermentables or hops, can have multiple values like shown in this prettified version
[image]

I have code to read and normalize the file:

```
import json

filename = 'recipes_full copy.json'

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    try:
        json_data = json.load(f)
        print("The JSON file is valid")
    except ValueError as e:
        print("The JSON file is invalid:", e)

print(json_data)

from pandas import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(json_data)
```

However the result is like this:

[image]

Question:
How can I flatten this to a full pandas daframe? specially if I dont know how many number of fermentables each recipe is going to have?

Update:

This is my code:

```
import json

filename = 'recipes_full copy.json'

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    try:
        json_data = json.load(f)
        print("The JSON file is valid")
    except ValueError as e:
        print("The JSON file is invalid:", e)

print(json_data)

from pandas import json_normalize
df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)           
df = df.T
df['fermentables'] = df['fermentables'].apply(pd.DataFrame)
df['hops'] = df['hops'].apply(pd.DataFrame)
df.at[0, 'hops']
```

erro:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[60], line 7
      5 df['fermentables'] = df['fermentables'].apply(pd.DataFrame)
      6 df['hops'] = df['hops'].apply(pd.DataFrame)
----> 7 df.at[0, 'hops']
...
   3807     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3808     #  the TypeError.
   3809     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys of your json are meant as index. Use `from_dict` with kwarg `orient='index'`:

```
import pandas as pd 

json_data = {"0": {"name": "Vanilla Cream Ale", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/1633/vanilla-cream-ale", "method": "All Grain", "style": "Cream Ale", "batch": 21.8, "og": 1.055, "fg": 1.013, "abv": 5.48, "ibu": 19.44, "color": 4.83, "ph mash": -1, "fermentables": [[2.381, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 44.7], [0.907, "American - White Wheat", 40.0, 2.8, 17.0], [0.907, "American - Pale 6-Row", 35.0, 1.8, 17.0], [0.227, "Flaked Corn", 40.0, 0.5, 4.3], [0.227, "American - Caramel / Crystal 20L", 35.0, 20.0, 4.3], [0.227, "American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)", 33.0, 1.8, 4.3], [0.113, "Flaked Barley", 32.0, 2.2, 2.1], [0.34, "Honey", 42.0, 2.0, 6.4]], "hops": [[14.0, "Cascade", "Pellet", 6.2, "Boil", "60 min", 11.42, 33.3], [14.0, "Cascade", "Pellet", 6.2, "Boil", "20 min", 6.92, 33.3], [14.0, "saaz", "Pellet", 3.0, "Boil", "5 min", 1.1, 33.3]], "hops Summary": [[28.0, "Cascade (Pellet)", 18.34, 66.6], [14.0, "saaz (Pellet)", 1.1, 33.3]], "other": [["2 oz", "pure vanilla extract", "Flavor", "Boil", "0 min."], ["1 oz", "pure vanilla extract", "Flavor", "Bottling", "0 min."], ["1 tsp", "yeast nutrient", "Other", "Boil", "15 min."], ["1 each", "whirlfloc", "Fining", "Boil", "15 min."], ["4 each", "Vanilla beans - in 2oz Vodka", "Other", "Secondary", "0 min."]], "yeast": ["Wyeast - K\u00f6lsch 2565", "76%", "Low", "56", "70", "Yes"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 16, "views": 289454},
"2": {"name": "Sierra Nevada Pale Ale Clone", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/28546/sierra-nevada-pale-ale-clone", "method": "All Grain", "style": "American Pale Ale", "batch": 24.6, "og": 1.055, "fg": 1.013, "abv": 5.58, "ibu": 39.79, "color": 8.0, "ph mash": 5.67, "fermentables": [[5.216, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 92.7], [0.412, "American - Caramel / Crystal 60L", 34.0, 60.0, 7.3]], "hops": [[14.0, "Magnum", "Pellet", 15.0, "Boil", "60 min", 22.62, 8.3], [14.0, "Perle", "Pellet", 8.2, "Boil", "30 min", 9.51, 8.3], [28.0, "Cascade", "Pellet", 7.0, "Boil", "10 min", 7.66, 16.7], [56.0, "Cascade", "Pellet", 7.0, "Boil", "0 min", 0, 33.3], [56.0, "Cascade", "Pellet", 7.0, "Dry Hop", "4 days", 0, 33.3]], "hops Summary": [[14.0, "Magnum (Pellet)", 22.62, 8.3], [14.0, "Perle (Pellet)", 9.51, 8.3], [140.0, "Cascade (Pellet)", 7.66, 83.3]], "other": [["1 each", "Crush whilrfoc Tablet", "Water Agt", "Boil", "10 min."]], "yeast": ["Fermentis - Safale - American Ale Yeast US-05", "76%", "Medium", "54", "77", "Yes"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 26, "views": 271945},
"3": {"name": "Zombie Dust Clone - ALL GRAIN", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/5916/zombie-dust-clone-all-grain", "method": "All Grain", "style": "American IPA", "batch": 22.7, "og": 1.061, "fg": 1.016, "abv": 5.94, "ibu": 62.42, "color": 8.5, "ph mash": 5.81, "fermentables": [[5.33, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 81.7], [0.513, "American - Munich - Light 10L", 33.0, 10.0, 7.9], [0.227, "German - CaraFoam", 37.0, 1.8, 3.5], [0.227, "American - Caramel / Crystal 60L", 34.0, 60.0, 3.5], [0.227, "German - Melanoidin", 37.0, 25.0, 3.5]], "hops": [[21.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "First Wort", "0 min", 15.57, 8.6], [35.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "15 min", 21.11, 14.3], [35.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "10 min", 15.43, 14.3], [35.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "5 min", 8.48, 14.3], [35.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "1 min", 1.83, 14.3], [84.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Dry Hop", "7 days", 0, 34.3]], "hops Summary": [[245.0, "Citra (Pellet)", 62.42, 100.1]], "other": [], "yeast": ["Fermentis - Safale - English Ale Yeast S-04", "75%", "High", "54", "77", "Yes"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 10, "views": 208996},
"4": {"name": "Russian River Pliny the Elder (original)", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/37534/russian-river-pliny-the-elder-original-", "method": "All Grain", "style": "Imperial IPA", "batch": 22.7, "og": 1.072, "fg": 1.018, "abv": 7.09, "ibu": 232.89, "color": 6.33, "ph mash": -1, "fermentables": [[6.01, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 87.2], [0.272, "American - Caramel / Crystal 40L", 34.0, 40.0, 3.9], [0.272, "American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)", 33.0, 1.8, 3.9], [0.34, "Corn Sugar - Dextrose ", 46.0, 0.5, 4.9]], "hops": [[98.0, "Columbus", "Pellet", 15.0, "Boil", "90 min", 171.54, 28.0], [21.0, "Columbus", "Pellet", 15.0, "Boil", "45 min", 31.54, 6.0], [28.0, "Simcoe", "Pellet", 12.7, "Boil", "30 min", 29.81, 8.0], [28.0, "Centennial", "Pellet", 10.0, "Aroma", "0 min", 0, 8.0], [70.0, "Simcoe", "Pellet", 12.7, "Aroma", "0 min", 0, 20.0], [28.0, "Columbus", "Pellet", 15.0, "Dry Hop", "13 days", 0, 8.0], [28.0, "Centennial", "Pellet", 10.0, "Dry Hop", "13 days", 0, 8.0], [28.0, "Simcoe", "Pellet", 12.7, "Dry Hop", "13 days", 0, 8.0], [7.0, "Columbus", "Pellet", 15.0, "Dry Hop", "5 days", 0, 2.0], [7.0, "Centennial", "Pellet", 10.0, "Dry Hop", "5 days", 0, 2.0], [7.0, "Simcoe", "Pellet", 12.7, "Dry Hop", "5 days", 0, 2.0]], "hops Summary": [[154.0, "Columbus (Pellet)", 203.08, 44.0], [133.0, "Simcoe (Pellet)", 29.81, 38.0], [63.0, "Centennial (Pellet)", 0.0, 18.0]], "other": [], "yeast": ["Wyeast - American Ale 1056", "75%", "Med-Low", "60", "72", "No"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 6, "views": 193832},
"5": {"name": "Spotted Clown (New Glarus Spotted Cow clone)", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/672/spotted-clown-new-glarus-spotted-cow-clone-", "method": "All Grain", "style": "Cream Ale", "batch": 20.8, "og": 1.054, "fg": 1.014, "abv": 5.36, "ibu": 21.27, "color": 5.94, "ph mash": -1, "fermentables": [[2.722, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 50.0], [0.907, "American - Munich - Light 10L", 33.0, 10.0, 16.7], [0.567, "Flaked Corn", 40.0, 0.5, 10.4], [0.794, "Flaked Barley", 32.0, 2.2, 14.6], [0.227, "American - Caramel / Crystal 10L", 35.0, 10.0, 4.2], [0.227, "American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)", 33.0, 1.8, 4.2]], "hops": [[14.0, "Cascade", "Pellet", 6.7, "Boil", "60 min", 12.67, 33.3], [14.0, "german select", "Pellet", 5.8, "Boil", "20 min", 6.64, 33.3], [14.0, "Willamette", "Pellet", 5.2, "Boil", "5 min", 1.96, 33.3]], "hops Summary": [[14.0, "Cascade (Pellet)", 12.67, 33.3], [14.0, "german select (Pellet)", 6.64, 33.3], [14.0, "Willamette (Pellet)", 1.96, 33.3]], "other": [["1 each", "whirlfloc", "Fining", "Boil", "15 min."], ["1 tsp", "yeast nutrient", "Other", "Boil", "15 min."]], "yeast": ["Wyeast - K\u00f6lsch 2565", "75%", "Low", "56", "70", "Yes"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 5, "views": 190059},
"6": {"name": "Chocolate Vanilla Porter", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/29265/chocolate-vanilla-porter", "method": "All Grain", "style": "Robust Porter", "batch": 22.7, "og": 1.06, "fg": 1.016, "abv": 5.77, "ibu": 31.36, "color": 34.76, "ph mash": -1, "fermentables": [[2.268, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 35.6], [1.361, "United Kingdom - Brown", 32.0, 65.0, 21.4], [0.907, "American - Munich - Light 10L", 33.0, 10.0, 14.2], [0.454, "American - Chocolate", 29.0, 350.0, 7.1], [0.454, "American - Caramel / Crystal 10L", 35.0, 10.0, 7.1], [0.454, "Flaked Oats", 33.0, 2.2, 7.1], [0.227, "American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)", 33.0, 1.8, 3.6], [0.113, "Brown Sugar", 45.0, 15.0, 1.8], [0.136, "Corn Sugar - Dextrose", 46.0, 0.5, 2.1]], "hops": [[28.0, "East Kent Goldings", "Pellet", 5.4, "Boil", "60 min", 18.38, 40.0], [21.0, "East Kent Goldings", "Pellet", 5.4, "Boil", "30 min", 10.59, 30.0], [21.0, "Willamette", "Pellet", 4.7, "Boil", "5 min", 2.39, 30.0]], "hops Summary": [[49.0, "East Kent Goldings (Pellet)", 28.97, 70.0], [21.0, "Willamette (Pellet)", 2.39, 30.0]], "other": [["6 oz", "organic cocoa powder", "Flavor", "Boil", "15 min."], ["1 oz", "pure vanilla extract", "Flavor", "Boil", "0 min."], ["1 tsp", "yeast nutrient", "Other", "Boil", "15 min."], ["2 each", "Vanilla bean", "Flavor", "Secondary", "--"]], "yeast": ["Wyeast - Irish Ale 1084", "73%", "Medium", "62", "72", "Yes"], "rating": 4, "num rating": 1, "views": 188822},
"7": {"name": "Zombie Dust Clone - EXTRACT", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/5920/zombie-dust-clone-extract", "method": "Extract", "style": "American IPA", "batch": 18.9, "og": 1.063, "fg": 1.016, "abv": 6.16, "ibu": 70.18, "color": 8.98, "ph mash": 5.41, "fermentables": [[2.722, "Dry Malt Extract - Extra Light", 42.0, 2.5, 70.6]], "hops": [[28.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "First Wort", "0 min", 25.02, 12.5], [28.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "15 min", 20.35, 12.5], [28.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "10 min", 14.87, 12.5], [28.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "5 min", 8.18, 12.5], [28.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "1 min", 1.77, 12.5], [84.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.0, "Dry Hop", "7 days", 0, 37.5]], "hops Summary": [[224.0, "Citra (Pellet)", 70.19, 100.0]], "other": [], "yeast": ["Fermentis - Safale - English Ale Yeast S-04", "75%", "High", "54", "77", "Yes"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 9, "views": 184124},
"8": {"name": "Southern Tier Pumking clone", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/16367/southern-tier-pumking-clone", "method": "All Grain", "style": "Holiday/Winter Special Spiced Beer", "batch": 20.8, "og": 1.083, "fg": 1.021, "abv": 8.16, "ibu": 50.22, "color": 15.64, "ph mash": -1, "fermentables": [[6.804, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 75.9], [0.907, "American - Victory", 34.0, 28.0, 10.1], [0.34, "American - Caramel / Crystal 80L", 33.0, 80.0, 3.8], [0.907, "pumpkin", 1.75, 13.0, 10.1]], "hops": [[28.0, "Magnum", "Pellet", 15.0, "Boil", "50 min", 41.13, 50.0], [28.0, "Sterling", "Pellet", 8.7, "Boil", "10 min", 9.1, 50.0]], "hops Summary": [[28.0, "Magnum (Pellet)", 41.13, 50.0], [28.0, "Sterling (Pellet)", 9.1, 50.0]], "other": [["0.75 lb", "Demerara sugar", "Flavor", "Boil", "1 hr."], ["0.25 lb", "Light Brown sugar", "Flavor", "Boil", "1 hr."], ["0.75 tsp", "Fresh ground ginger", "Spice", "Boil", "5 min."], ["3 each", "Ceylon cinnamon sticks", "Spice", "Boil", "5 min."], ["0.50 tsp", "Whole cloves", "Spice", "Boil", "5 min."], ["0.50 tsp", "Nutmeg", "Spice", "Boil", "5 min."], ["0.50 tsp", "Allspice", "Spice", "Boil", "5 min."], ["1 each", "Vanilla Bean vodka solution (see notes for exact quantities)", "Spice", "Secondary", "--"], ["1 tsp", "Pumpkin pie spice", "Spice", "Secondary", "--"], ["1 tsp", "Capella water soluble Graham Cracker Extract (purchased online)", "Spice", "Secondary", "--"]], "yeast": ["Wyeast - American Ale 1056", "75%", "Med-Low", "60", "72", "No"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 15, "views": 181369},
"9": {"name": "Bakke Brygg Belgisk Blond 50 L", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/89534/bakke-brygg-belgisk-blond-50-l", "method": "All Grain", "style": "Belgian Blond Ale", "batch": 50.0, "og": 1.062, "fg": 1.012, "abv": 6.52, "ibu": 18.54, "color": 4.35, "ph mash": -1, "fermentables": [[11.0, "Castle Malting Pilsen 2RP/2RS", 37.0, 1.8, 88.0], [0.5, "Castle Malting Abbey", 33.0, 17.4, 4.0], [1.0, "Farin, hvit", 46.0, 0.0, 8.0]], "hops": [[64.0, "Hallertau Mittelfruh", "Pellet", 4.0, "Boil", "60 min", 13.36, 56.1], [50.0, "Hallertau Mittelfruh", "Pellet", 4.0, "Boil", "15 min", 5.18, 43.9]], "hops Summary": [[114.0, "Hallertau Mittelfruh (Pellet)", 18.54, 100.0]], "other": [], "yeast": ["Fermentis - Safbrew - Specialty Ale Yeast T-58", "80%", "High", "12", "25", "No"], "rating": 0, "num rating": 5, "views": 172811},
"10": {"name": "Mango Habanero IPA", "url": "/homebrew/recipe/view/61082/mango-habanero-ipa", "method": "All Grain", "style": "Imperial IPA", "batch": 20.8, "og": 1.086, "fg": 1.018, "abv": 8.88, "ibu": 98.09, "color": 8.55, "ph mash": 5.69, "fermentables": [[6.804, "American - Pale 2-Row", 37.0, 1.8, 81.1], [0.907, "American - Caramel / Crystal 20L", 35.0, 20.0, 10.8], [0.454, "Flaked Wheat", 34.0, 2.0, 5.4], [0.227, "Rolled Oats", 33.0, 2.2, 2.7]], "hops": [[35.0, "Magnum", "Pellet", 15.0, "Boil", "60 min", 57.62, 16.7], [28.0, "Centennial", "Pellet", 10.0, "Boil", "30 min", 23.62, 13.3], [35.0, "Centennial", "Pellet", 10.0, "Boil", "10 min", 13.93, 16.7], [28.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 11.1, "Boil", "1 min", 1.47, 13.3], [28.0, "Zythos", "Pellet", 11.0, "Boil", "1 min", 1.46, 13.3], [14.0, "Centennial", "Pellet", 10.0, "Dry Hop", "0 days", 0, 6.7], [28.0, "Citra", "Pellet", 10.0, "Dry Hop", "0 days", 0, 13.3], [14.0, "Zythos", "Pellet", 11.0, "Dry Hop", "0 days", 0, 6.7]], "hops Summary": [[35.0, "Magnum (Pellet)", 57.62, 16.7], [77.0, "Centennial (Pellet)", 37.55, 36.7], [28.0, "Citra (Pellet)", 1.47, 13.3], [42.0, "Zythos (Pellet)", 1.46, 20.0], [28.0, "Citra (Pellet)", 0, 13.3]], "other": [["1 each", "Whirlfloc Tab", "Fining", "Boil", "5 min."], ["44 oz", "Pureed Frozen Mango", "Flavor", "Boil", "5 min."], ["1 each", "Pureed Habanero Pepper", "Flavor", "Boil", "5 min."], ["32 oz", "Organic Mango Juice", "Flavor", "Secondary", "0 min."], ["1 each", "Sliced Habanero Pepper", "Flavor", "Secondary", "0 min."]], "yeast": ["White Labs - California Ale Yeast WLP001", "76.5%", "Medium", "68", "73", "Yes"], "rating": 5, "num rating": 6, "views": 172664}
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_data, orient='index')
```

Output:

```
                                           name                                                url  ... num rating   views
0                             Vanilla Cream Ale       /homebrew/recipe/view/1633/vanilla-cream-ale  ...         16  289454
1                  Sierra Nevada Pale Ale Clone  /homebrew/recipe/view/28546/sierra-nevada-pale...  ...         26  271945
2                 Zombie Dust Clone - ALL GRAIN  /homebrew/recipe/view/5916/zombie-dust-clone-a...  ...         10  208996
3      Russian River Pliny the Elder (original)  /homebrew/recipe/view/37534/russian-river-plin...  ...          6  193832
4  Spotted Clown (New Glarus Spotted Cow clone)  /homebrew/recipe/view/672/spotted-clown-new-gl...  ...          5  190059
5                      Chocolate Vanilla Porter  /homebrew/recipe/view/29265/chocolate-vanilla-...  ...          1  188822
6                   Zombie Dust Clone - EXTRACT  /homebrew/recipe/view/5920/zombie-dust-clone-e...  ...          9  184124
7                   Southern Tier Pumking clone  /homebrew/recipe/view/16367/southern-tier-pumk...  ...         15  181369
8                Bakke Brygg Belgisk Blond 50 L  /homebrew/recipe/view/89534/bakke-brygg-belgis...  ...          5  172811
9                            Mango Habanero IPA     /homebrew/recipe/view/61082/mango-habanero-ipa  ...          6  172664
```

Edit: you can make dataframes from the lists like `fermentables` and `hops` with `apply`:

```
df['fermentables'] = df['fermentables'].apply(pd.DataFrame)
df['hops'] = df['hops'].apply(pd.DataFrame)
```

You can then access these dataframes from `df` index:

```
df.at['0', 'hops']
```

Output:

```
      0        1       2    3     4       5      6     7
0  14.0  Cascade  Pellet  6.2  Boil  60 min  11.42  33.3
1  14.0  Cascade  Pellet  6.2  Boil  20 min   6.92  33.3
2  14.0     saaz  Pellet  3.0  Boil   5 min   1.10  33.3
```

Comment: I would like fermentables and hops to be separate dataframes with an id pointing to the main dataframe via its id

Comment: You don't need to separate the dataframes. The cells inside df can be dataframes. Check my edited answer!

Comment: please see my update, with my new code.

Comment: the full dataset is this: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/angeredsquid/brewers-friend-beer-recipes

Comment: Why don't you create your df from `json_data.values()` like I suggested? An alternative is `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_data, orient='index')`

Comment: oh yes, that works! another question, how can I rename the column names of the hops and fermentables dataframes?  its the first time i Know that you can have a pandas dataframe inside a column of a dataframe,  will ML algorithms understand this format? Lets say I want a Classification Algorithm to predict beer style based on recipe ingredients (fermentables and hops)

Comment: Note: using `from_dict` the index will be of type string, so use `df.at['0', 'hops']` instead of `df.at[0, 'hops']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252245/discussion-between-luis-valencia-and-tranbi).

Comment: To specify the columns use a lambda function: `.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x, columns=your_cols))`